# Javascript - single line reduce statement not working becoz of push statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

// only have numbers in array till n times

```
function deleteNth(arr,n){
    // ...
    function count(arr1, num){
        console.log('arr1', arr1)
        return arr1.reduce((acc, val) => (val === num) ? ++acc : acc, 0);
    }
    // return arr.reduce((acc1, val1) => {
    //     if (count(acc1, val1) < n){
    //         acc1.push(val1);
    //     }
    //     else{
    //         acc1;
    //     }
    //     return acc1;
    // }, []);
    return arr.reduce((acc1, val1) => ((count(acc1, val1) < n) ? acc1.push(val1) : acc1), []);
  }

  
console.log(deleteNth([20,37,20,21], 1));    // [20,37,21]`
```

when i run with this code am getting error.
TypeError: arr1.reduce is not a function

however when i run with the commented code, its running fine.
with multiple lines of code in reduce function, its working fine.

in single line code, variable acc1 is having value 1 when first array element is processed. due to this am getting error.
can anyone advise what mistake am doing?

console.log(deleteNth([20,37,20,21], 1));    // [20,37,21]

Comment: Your second reduce callback is returning acc1.push(val) instead of returning acc1.

Comment: so i have to give return without push command like below,

'''    
    return arr.reduce((acc1, val1) => (count(acc1, val1) < n) ? (acc1.push(val1) ? acc1: acc1): acc1, []);
'''
this is working.

but is this effective way of writing code?

Comment: If you delete the else clause from the commented code it should work fine as a replacement.  I would avoid forcing ternaries, if they don't work nicely don't use them, it makes the code really hard to understand.

Comment: commented code is working fine (multi lines in reduce code.

single line reduce statement is not working becoz of push command in return

Comment: Change `acc1.push(val1)` to `acc1.push(val1) && acc1`, that's all to chain operations and return acc1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you should be returning the array in the `reduce` callback, but one branch of the ternary is returning the result of `push`, which is the new length of the array.

You could exploit the logical and operator to `push` only when the condition is true and use the comma operator to always return the accumulator array at the end.

```js
function deleteNth(arr, n) {
  function count(arr1, num) {
    return arr1.reduce((acc, val) => (val === num) ? ++acc : acc, 0);
  }
  return arr.reduce((acc1, val1) => (count(acc1, val1) < n && acc1.push(val1), acc1), []);
}
console.log(deleteNth([20, 37, 20, 21], 1)); // [20,37,21]
```